# Unknown red wiring harness near cooling fan area on a Ford Focus 2004

Tags: electrical, ford, wiring, focus

I have a 2004 Ford Focus SE DOHC. Today, I opened the hood and found an unconnected red wiring harness (shown in the picture, it's the one with a question mark pointed at). I looked around the area but could not find any female connectors for it. When the engine is running, there were no warning lights or error messages. Though the car is drivable, I just don't want any part to break because this harness wasn't plugged in. Does anyone know where this harness is supposed to go? Thank you very much for your help!

[image]

Comment: it doesnt look like its ever been covered (due to the grime on it) could be a diagnostic port but you'll need to wait till someone that knows better comes along

Comment: I would've suspected that it is the engine coolant temperature sensor but it looks like this model of Focus [doesn't have one](http://www.justanswer.com/ford/3szk5-coolant-temp-sensor-locate-2003-ford-focus.html#).

Comment: It's not easy to find pictures/videos on the internet to see where this hose is leading to. It would be great if you can post up some pictures from different angles.

Comment: I wish I could upvote twice. AMAZING circles, arrows and lines!

Comment: 8th digit of the vin?

Comment: As a sidenote, I believe that is technically the `female` half of the connector.  The "gender" of connectors depends on where the actual metal pins are, not the shape of the plastic housing.

Answer (score 2):

It's C1311 for the power steering pressure sensor.

[image]